# iOS - what is involved in creating an entitlements enabled, "white label" iOS apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, white-labelling

I'm currently exploring my options for offering the same app to multiple clients with different icons,name, etc.

The app uses push notifications through Parse.com. **What steps are involved in creating a new "white label" iOS app from the same xCode project?**

- Create unique App IDs for each client?
- Create new development/distribution profiles for each client?
- Create a new xCode target for each client?
- Register new app in Parse.com for each client?
- Specify unique parse API keys for each target?
- Create an App store entry for each white label app?
- Write sales copy, upload screenshots?
- Update X number of white label apps each time the app is updated?

I know that Apple offers "secret" APIs to developers that make money for Apple, has anyone heard of an easier way to white label a profitable app?

Comment: Nice to-do list, where's the question ?

Comment: I'm asking if I'm misunderstanding some of the steps listed. In particular, unique app IDs and codesigning seems like a major pain.

Comment: You're going to need to have unique IDs and subsequently unique certificates/profiles for each. It is a pain, but that is what's required for separate applications. The only thing you can do to make this process easier is manage each white label in its own target within the same app to avoid replicating all the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create multiple targets inside your project with distinct app IDs, and all of your versions can use the same shared code, with some sort of way to distinguish color schemes/themes/media for each version - I've created otherwise identical plists for each "flavor" with the same keys but different values identifying things like titles, image filenames, etc.

You'll need to create a unique APNS certificates for each as each cert is tied to a single app ID (I believe). Otherwise, your list is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Been looking into this question and found the following on the Apple website:
https://developer.apple.com/business/custom-apps/

The intent, it appears, is for ISVs to privately distribute custom (or customized) apps to enterprise customers.   I doubt this program existed when @AlexStone asked his question.  But the question is still highly relevant and, hopefully, Apple has a better answer for us now.  Which leaves Android ...